# Julia plot function stopped working properly

Tags: plot, julia

Fore some reason Julia refuses to plot my code

```
using Plots

n = 100
ϕ = range(0,stop=2*π,length=n)
x =  cos.(ϕ)';
y =  sin.(ϕ)';
plot(x,y)
```

[image]

The last time I used the same code Julia plotted:
[image]

and I already tried

[image]

I didn't change anything since the last time when Julia's plot function worked properly. so I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

Comment: btw I am using Julia 1.6.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try instead just

```
using Plots

n = 100
ϕ = range(0,stop=2*π,length=n)
x =  cos.(ϕ);
y =  sin.(ϕ);
plot(x,y)
```

The transposes are turning the results into row vectors, and Plots is trying to plot each column as a separate series.

Comment: It works. However, I am concerned on why it stopped working from last time

Comment: Yeah, I’m not sure why it would have ever worked the other way

Comment: I ended up resetting my pc. It resolved any issues I had with Julia

Answer (score 1):

FWIW, you can also plot a parametric function *t* ↦ [*x*(*t*), *y*(*t*)] with `plot(x, y, t)`, e.g.,

```
plot(cos, sin, range(0,2π,length=100))
```